# A problem about $\pi$-groups (Isaacs' Finite Group Theory)

Tags: group-theory

I was trying to solve the following problem in [Isaacs' Finite Group Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC&pg=PA13#v=onepage):

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $\pi$ a set of primes.
>
> a) Show that there exists a (unique) normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $G/N$ is a $\pi$-group and such that it is contained in any normal subgroup $M\lhd G$ such that $G/M$ is a $\pi$-group.
>
> b) Show that this group $N$ is generated by the set of all elements in $G$ whose order is not divisible by any prime in $\pi$.

As for the first point I think I have no problems: I define $N$ to be the intersection of all the normal subgroups which satisfy the property in a) and I prove that this intersection is characteristic in $G$ and satisfies also the same property. As for the second point, I have proved that the generated subgroup must be contained in any normal subgroup with the property in a), and so it is contained in $N$; however, I cannot prove the other inclusion. I thought that the best way was to prove that this generated subgroup is normal in $G$ and again satisfies the same property. I proved that this subgroup, which I call $S$, is characteristic in $G$, hence normal, but I don't know how to prove that the quotient group $G/S$ is a $\pi$-group. I tried to argue by contradiction: if there exists a prime $q$ not in $\pi$ which divides $|G/S|$, then by Cauchy's Thm there will be an element $xS\in G/S$ of order $q$; then by using the isomorphism $\frac{G/S}{N/S}\cong G/N$ and the fact that $G/N$ is a $\pi$-group it must be $x\in N$. But now I have no idea about how to continue in order to derive a contradiction.

Can anyone help me, please? Thank you so much for sharing your ideas!

Comment: I guess you should say that $G$ is solvable otherwise it is not true. Can you tell the index of question in the book?

Comment: It's problem 1B8 at page 13 of the book.

Comment: :http://www.math.umn.edu/~bahra004/fgt.pdf here is the solution of isac's book's first two cheapter.(it is solved by isacs himsel you can trust the solution :))

Comment: @mesel No, solvability is definitely not required here.

Comment: @Diogenes: for part (b) one direction is lagrange's theorem and the other is cauchy's theorem.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Yes,I see the reason.thanks

Comment: Thanks mesel for the pdf, now I understand! Thanks also to the other users! Do I have to write down the solution in the answers below, according to you?

Comment: @Diogenes: it is a good idea to post the solution here. You get votes, and you can make sure it is right before handing it in.  (BTW the pdf is not by Marty Isaacs, but rather by Cihan Bahran, a student of Peter Webb).

Comment: @all users: I wrote down the answer in my personal way, trying to be as clear as possible. Please write if there is something wrong. Btw, I think that the idea of using Bézout's identity is amazing, and this identity is an extremely powerful tool. I should remember to use it more than I do. Thanks to all, have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For sake of completeness, I write here what I have understood about the ideas underlying the solution of the exercise (so everybody should feel free to say if something is wrong).

a) Define $N:= \bigcap \{M \mid M\lhd G \,\,\text{and} \,\,G/M \,\,\text{is a}\,\,\pi-\text{group}\}$. Since every automorphism of $G$ preserves the order and the normality of groups, it follows that $N$ includes its image under every automorphism, and so by passing to inverse automorphisms we obtain actually equality between these two sets. So $N$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$, in particular normal. Furthermore, by the third isomorphism theorem we have that $\frac{G/N}{M/N}\cong G/M$ for every $M\lhd G$ s.t. $G/M$ is a $\pi$-group. If by contradiction there were a prime $p\notin \pi$ which divides $|G/N|$, then by Cauchy's Theorem there would be an element $xN\in G/N$ of order $p$. But then its image $xN(M/N)\in \frac{G/N}{M/N}$ under the canonical projection would have as order a divisor of $p$, so it must be 1 because $G/M$ is a $\pi$-group. So $xN\in M/N$ and so $x\in M$. Since this holds for every $M$ which satisfies the property above, we obtain $x\in N$, and so $xN=N$ has order one, absurd.

b) Define $S:=\langle \, g\in G \mid \text{ord}(g) \,\,\text{has no prime divisor in}\,\, \pi\rangle$.

$S\subseteq N$: It suffices to show that if $g\in G$ has order not divisible by any prime in $\pi$, then it belongs to any normal subgroup $M$ such that $G/M$ is a $\pi$-group. Take $gM\in G/M$. Its order must be a divisor of the order of $g$ in $G$ and it must also be a divisor of $|G/M|$, so it must have any prime divisor simultaneously not in $\pi$ and in $\pi$. So it cannot have prime divisors, hence it must be equal to one, i.e. $gM=M$, i.e. $g\in M$.

$N\subseteq S$: By the property of point a) it suffices to show that $S\lhd G$ and $G/S$ is a $\pi$-group. By the same argument of above, the automorphisms of $G$ preserve orders, so it follows that the subgroup $S$ is characteristic in $G$, hence normal. It suffices to show that $G/S$ is a $\pi$-group. Take a prime divisor $p$ of $|G/S|$. By Cauchy's theorem there exists an element $gS\in G/S$ of order $p$, so that $g^p\in S$ is the least positive power of $g$ which belongs to $S$. Write now $\text{ord}(g)=p^kn$, for some natural numbers $k$ and $n$ with $\text{gcd}(p,n)=1$. By this extremely powerful weapon called Bézout's identity, there exist integers $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ap+bn=1$, and so we have $g^{ap+bn}=g\notin S$, and so it must be also $g^n\notin S$ (because we already know that $g^{ap}\in S$). But now we have $g^n\notin S$, so by definition of $S$ we have that $\text{ord}(g^n)=p^k$ must have at least one prime divisor in $\pi$, and this prime divisor can only be $p$ itself. Hence $p\in \pi$, and so $G/S$ is a $\pi$-group.

Comment: Looks good. :-)

Comment: @Diogenes: A beautiful argument! Thank you for taking the time to answer your own question.